# How should I organise a multi-connection client using twisted?

Tags: python, twisted

I'm new to twisted, and I'm having trouble working out how I should organise my code. The client connects to a TCP(SSL) control channel and then will try to connect to the same IP:port on UDP for a low-latency data channel, based on encryption settings provided over TCP. If it can't, the TCP control channel will be used for the data. I'd like to write a reusable client such that people can override a class with functions such as dataReceived, controlMessageXReceived, sendControlMessageX, sendDataMessage etc, with whether the UDP channel is in use or not abstracted away into my code.

I currently have a Protocol that can understand the TCP control channel; for testing purposes I've overridden ConnectionMade() there to send set-up messages and confirm everything works (it can understand the server and vice versa) but I have no idea how to integrate that into a wider context.

(*For the curious, this is a client for [Mumble](http://mumble.sourceforge.net/) - this protocol specification is [here](https://github.com/mumble-voip/mumble/raw/master/doc/mumble-protocol.pdf), and I'm trying to update [this](http://frymaster.127001.org/mumble/) horrible pile of umaintainable (multithreaded) code into something modern*)

Answer (score 1):

Consider mirroring the protocol/transport separation already present in Twisted.

`Protocol` doesn't know anything about TCP.  It just knows how to handle a stream of bytes.  It's the transport that knows about TCP (or TLS, or UNIX sockets, or something else).

There is an explicit interface between `Protocol` and its transport (actually, there are two - `IProtocol` lets a transport know what it can do to the protocol object and `ITransport` lets the protocol know what it can do to the transport object).

Invent an interface that makes sense for the application you're working with.  For example, `Protocol` has `dataReceived` because "some bytes arrived" is one of the things that happens with "a stream of bytes".  What things can happen in Mumble?  For example these things might be, "a user connected to the server" or "a message arrived in the channel you're in".  Your interface might have a method for each of these.

Now application developers can implement their own novel behavior by writing an implementation of this interface - which is explicitly and completely defined - and then plugging that implementation into your library (for example, perhaps your library could offer a `connectToMumbleServer(address, mumbleApplicationObject)` API).

Your library knows exactly what it's allowed to do with the application object because the interface is explicitly defined.  If you repeat this process for the opposite direction then the application developer will know what they can do to the mumble server using your library, too (eg "join a channel" or "send a packet of audio data").

You *could* provide a base class (like `Protocol`) for applications to subclass but this is a very minor bit of convenience.  In case you haven't recently, open up `twisted/internet/protocols.py` and look at the implementation of the `Protocol` class.  There's almost nothing there and none of what is there is very complicated or difficult to replicate.  If application developers had to start off subclassing `object` and type out all of the methods themselves they wouldn't be at much of a disadvantage.